# Can pilots use PAN PAN Medical, even if they were not on MedEvac mission?

Tags: phraseology, medevac

If there is a medical emergency on board, on a passenger or crew member, will the crew be cleared to use PAN PAN/MAYDAY MEDICAL on their R/T?

Is there any DOC in which regulates these phraseology?

Answer (score 10):

The UK CAA Radiotelephony Manual (CAP 413) has the following to say about it:

> PAN PAN MEDICAL is not used in the UK but refers to a Geneva
>   Convention term associated with medical transportation by parties
>   involved in a conflict.
>
> Use of this term is not appropriate in the UK.

Which seems to be a pretty definitive no. Personally, I'd not heard of the term but assuming the CAA's interpretation of the ICAO's definition (i.e., for use during war) then I can't imagine it ever being appropriate outside of that use.

That said, why would you need to? Using a normal MAYDAY or PAN call and describing the emergency as a medical one is perfectly acceptable and would be fully understood by all parties.

Comment: The last paragraph is the definitive answer.

Answer (score 6):

No. The phrase 'PAN PAN Medical' is reserved exclusively for medical transports. From ICAO [Annex 10 to the Convention on International Civil Aviation- Aeronautical Telecommunications Volume II](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/anconf12/Document%20Archive/AN10_V2_cons%5B1%5D.pdf):

> For the purpose of announcing and identifying aircraft used for medical transports, a transmission of the radiotelephony urgency signal PAN PAN, preferably spoken three times, and each word of the group pronounced as the
> French word “panne”, shall be followed by the radiotelephony signal for medical transports MAY-DEE-CAL, pronounced as in the French “médical”. The use of the signals described above indicates that the message which follows concerns a protected medical transport.

However, the pilot can use PAN-PAN followed by request for medical advise if the situation is urgent. According to [FAA Air Traffic Organization Policy, Air Traffic Control](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf), PAN-PAN is used in case of urgency.

> A pilot who encounters a Distress condition should declare an emergency by beginning the initial communication with the word “Mayday,” preferably repeated three times. For an Urgency condition, the word “Pan-Pan” should be used in the same manner.
>
> PAN-PAN- The international radio-telephony urgency signal. When repeated three times, indicates uncertainty or alert followed by the nature of the
> urgency.

So, PAN-PAN followed by request for medical advise is ok.

Comment: It's worth stating that a pilot who is experiencing a medical problem should call a mayday whereas if it is a passenger having a medical problem it's a pan-pan.

Comment: @GdD, I believe a passenger with medical problem might warrant a mayday too if the problem is life-threatening, no? Of course the bar is much lower for pilot.

Comment: Mayday calls should be reserved for problems that impact the safety of the flight, and a passenger illness generally doesn't count. It's really moot, if you tell ATC you have a seriously ill passenger you will get priority.

Comment: I would agree with Jan Hudec here. Mayday is a distress call that should be used when the aircraft requires immediate assistance (CAO  Phraseology  Reference  Guide). If a passenger is in immediate life danger, I would most likely declare an emergency with a mayday call.